# Xcode. How download files at the stage of project assembly?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm doing an iOS framework and now i need to implement something like this: At the stage of the project assembly, I want to make a request to the server, get the JSON in response and write it to the project file. Thus, the user who downloaded the application, and opened it without the Internet will already have these files. In Android, it is possible to implement this function using the Gradle plugin. What the right way to implement this in iOS? Thanks in advance for the answer.

Comment: [tag:assembly] is not the right SO tag for this.  It only covers assembly-language (https://stackoverflow.com/tags/assembly/info), not the build process of an app.  Unfortunately I don't know what the right tag is, but hopefully someone can add an appropriate tag.  I've removed `[assembly]` because it definitely doesn't apply.

Comment: When you build the project (with Xcode) you want to download some JSON and embed that in the finished build so that the app customer has those files available to them regardless of internet connection?

Comment: You can insert a Run Script phase into your app target's Build Phases.

Comment: @WarrenBurton yes, its actually what i want

Comment: @WarrenBurton and there is an opportunity to do the same, but without creating ready-made files (like sometting.json) initially? Let's say I download some kind of configuration, I get a list of languages in it (it's equal to N, for example), and at the compilation stage I also want to load N localization files. But before compiling, I do not know what files it will be and how many will be. Thank you a lot!

Comment: Probably skip step 1 & 2. Add the files to the directly to the bundle using the environment vars `BUILD_DIR` and `something_FOLDER_PATH`.  You can enumerate at runtime with `Bundle.urls(forResourcesWithExtension...`.

Comment: @WarrenBurton i tryed it, and it's not work.. i suppose im making smth wrong. Script:

`MYFILE=${BUILD_DIR}/configuration.json 
curl -o $MYFILE https://my-api.com/api`

the file really create in build folder, but

`let fURL = Bundle.main.urls(forResourcesWithExtension: "json",
                                      subdirectory: "")`

actually return nil.. What is my mistake? Thank you

Comment: Use your eyes. Examine the contents of the folder where your download is going. Examine the paths. You want the file *inside* the package. There are a crapton of env vars that end *_FOLDER_PATH*.

Comment: @WarrenBurton The problem is that the file created by the script is in the project folder, but it is not included in the Target Membership... I think this problem can not be solved

Comment: It can be solved. You need to experiment a little with the info you have been given. e.g `$CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR/$CONTENTS_FOLDER_PATH/Resources` is the path to the bundle's resource directory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a `Run Script` phase in the Build Phases section of your project.

**Step 1**

Add the initial version of the file to your project. Make sure it's added to the target.

[image]

**Step 2**

Select your project and go the build phases tab. You should be able to see the file being copied to the bundle in the *Copy Bundle Resources* section.

[image]

**Step 3**

Add a new *Run Script* to your build. Click the plus button at the top-left of the editor.

1. Give the phase a sensible name by double clicking the label.
2. Reorder the phase as early as possible by dragging it up the list.

[image]

**Step 4**

Using your favourite scripting language/command line thing download the new file and replace the existing file.

e.g (untested demo bash sample, probably wont work)

```
MYFILE=${TEMP_DIR}/something.json
curl -o $MYFILE https://myserver.com/stuff/something-latest.json
cp -f $MYFILE ${SRCROOT}/Sploopy/Resources/something.json
```

You can examine the environment with the build inspector and see what values you can use to get the file in place.

[image]

Ones that will come in handy are:

- `TEMP_DIR` is a good place to put files temporarily.
- `SRCROOT` so you know where to copy the downloaded file to.
- `CONFIGURATION` so you can choose when to do this action. Personally I would only do it on `Release` but YMMV. It will be a blocking action.

**Step 5**

Profit